# namespace: cannot call member function without object

Tags: c++

I'm creating a event queue inside a namespace and the goal is be able to call it from anywhere (like a static class function).

So I have the namespace in eventManager.h

```
namespace atreus {
    class Event;

    class EventManager {
      private:
        std::queue<Event *> events;
      public:
        void pushEvent(Event *event);
        bool pollEvent(Event *event);
    };
}
```

and then I try to call the pushEvent in another class like:
object.cpp

```
inline void createEvent(sf::Vector2f& n, float penetration, sf::Vector2f velocity, float totalMass)
{
    atreus::Event *event;
    // adding stuff to event 
    atreus::EventManager::pushEvent(event);
}
```

And then I get this error:

```
cannot call member function ‘void atreus::EventManager::pushEvent(atreus::Event*)’ without object
 atreus::EventManager::pushEvent(event);
```

I've tried to add the function createEvent into a class and create a EventManager eventManager inside the namespace but nothing...

Comment: You didn't post the code line where the error happens.

Comment: `atreus::EventManager::pushEvent(event);` -> wrong. Either you need an instance of `EventManager` to call method for (e.g. `EventManager evtMgr; evtMgr.pushEvent(event);`) or you have to make `EventManager::pushEvent()` `static`. Btw. `atreus::Event *event;` is an uninitialized raw-pointer...

Comment: @Scheff Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void pushEvent(Event *event);
```

This is a non-static function, it cannot be called without an object.
Somewhere you should have an instance of `EventManager` and use the instance to call `pushEvent()`

If you want to be able to call this function without object, you need to mark this function as static.

```
static void pushEvent(Event *event);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the object before using it.

```
atreus::EventManager mgr;
mgr.pushEvent(event);
```

But you need to think of the lifetime of the object as well.

Preferable use an interface to EventManager  as class member and inject the class in the constructor.